# How to update a text[] field with a string

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a field called tags which can contain any number of strings:

```
                                Table "public.page"
        Column        |           Type           |            Modifiers
----------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------
 tags                 | text[]                   | not null default ARRAY[]::text[]
```

I want to add a string to the tags field - but I can't seem to get the concat function to work for me.  I've tried:

```
update page set tags=concat('My New String',tags);
ERROR:  function concat(unknown, text[]) does not exist
LINE 1: update page set tags=concat('My New String',tags) where ...
                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

and

```
update page set tags=('My New String'||tags);
ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown || text[]
LINE 1: update page set tags = ('My New String' || tags) where w...
                                                    ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The string "no luck" is not a built-in error message in PostgreSQL.

Comment: The `||` operator *should* work.  What error message are you getting?

Comment: Hmmm, for some reason, it doesn't understand that `'My New String'` is supposed to be text. Try casting it as such.

Comment: Alternatively, use the proper functions `array_prepend` or `array_append`, instead of `concat` which is not meant for arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PostgreSQL's type system, the literal `'My New String'` is not a `varchar` or `text` value, but a literal of type `unknown`, which can be processed as any type. (For instance, the literal for a `date` could be `'2013-08-29'`; this would not be processed as a `varchar` and then converted to `date`, it would be interpreted as a "`date` literal" at a very low level.)

Often, PostgreSQL can deduce the type automatically, but when it can't, you need to use one of the following to tell it that you want the literal to be treated as `text`:

- `text 'My New String'` (SQL standard literal syntax)
- `Cast('My New String' as text)` (SQL standard cast syntax, but not really a cast in this context)
- `'My New String'::text` (PostgreSQL non-standard cast syntax, but quite readable)

In your case , the error message `operator is not unique: unknown || text[]` is saying that there are multiple types that Postgres could interpret the literal as, each with their own definition of the `||` operator.

You therefore need something like this (I've removed the unnecessary parentheses):

```
update page set tags = 'My New String'::text || tags;
```

Comment: OK - that worked - it did the update using that syntax (Thank you very much for your detailed answer - I'm learning!)

Comment: The explanation of the type issue in play here with 'quoted' values is a revelation, and saved me hours of tearing my hair out. Thank you!

Comment: Will above query add a new string in text[] array or it replaces existing value in text[] array column

Comment: @SumitKandoi There isn't a meaningful difference between your two options. Like any update statement, the example is setting the value of a column (in this case, `tags`) to the result of an expression (the part following the `=` sign). That expression happens to reference the current value of the same column, specifically "an array consisting of everything currently in `tags` on this row, plus the string `'My New String'`". It works exactly the same way as `update some_table set some_number = some_number + 1` - the expression is evaluated, and then saved to the column.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `||` to concatenate?

```
select array['abc','def']::text[] || 'qwerty'::text;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE

Note: this answer was in response to the OP's original (unedited) question. Other answers contain more detail relevant to the updated question.

Comment: Yes - thanks for your input - sorry I didn't give you all of the info up front!